# Cannot add libraries in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, scapy

I want to add scapy library in pycharm. I made one project and then want to add libraries using Settings > Preferences > Project > Project Interpreter but the '+' sign (present at top right) is disabled. See screenshot below[image]
I am stuck. Please help

Comment: My guess is to press the Install packaging tools link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have pip installed in your machine.

1. click that yellow line at the bottom install python packaging tools
2. restart pycharm
3. go and add packages what you need

Comment: tried it but following  error is coming: 40:357: execution error: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'

Comment: first of all you have 2 version of python. 2.6 and 2.7, unistall 2.6 and then try, better will be if you uninstall both and install python3

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to install "Python packaging"

you may try using pip command:
 pip install scapy

Comment: i installed it using pip but how pycharm will know that it is installed  ?

Comment: do you have only one python installation in your machine?